# How to pass event.target to an objects method

Tags: javascript

I have a simple html table with two cells.  When one of the cells is clicked, a textbox appears. When the enter or tab key is pressed, the textbox should be hidden.  I finally got my code to work but not sure why it's working.  How can I pass event.target to my hide function properly?  It does not work the way that I'm doing it.  Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
   <table border="1">
 <tr>
   <th>Region</th>
   <th>Region Lead</th>       
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>Eastern</td>
   <td onclick="test.unhide()"><input type="text" value="Press enter or click tab" id="eastern" style="display:none" onkeypress="test.hide()" onkeydown="test.hide()"/>click me</td>
 </tr>
```

**JavaScript**

```
test = {
  unhide: function(){
console.log("show textbox");
document.getElementById("eastern").style.display = "inline";
 },
 hide: function(e){
var eastern = document.getElementById("eastern");
 eastern.addEventListener("keyup","keydown", function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  //Enter = 13, Tab = 9
  if (e.which === 13 || e.which === 9){
        console.log("Hide textbox");
        console.log("Update SharePoint List");
        eastern.style.display = "none";
  }
  });
 }
}
```

I'm also very open to improvements to the code.  I have the [codepen](https://codepen.io/isogunro/pen/MzNoWg?editors=1011) as well.

Comment: where is event defined? you should not be relying on window.event, because it is not supported in all browsers.

Comment: @epascarello — That is what the question is asking

Comment: [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event).

Comment: Oh, it's going to the global namespace?

Comment: @Quentin, it's not a duplicate because for me it's not a browser issue.

Comment: @OLA — You want to know where `event` comes from, the duplicate tells you. The duplicate is a duplicate.

Comment: @Quentin, ok.  I will modify the question